# Distributted Locking Mechanism AWS DynamoDB with Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm working on a project in which I have two actions - delete and write, and I need to make them "atomic", i.e., to be performed without any other process reading from the database after the data was deleted but not yet written.

The code under the `Concept Demonstration` rubric demonstrates the desired outcome with the use of `multiprocessing.Process` and `multiprocessing.Pipe` objects:

**Concept Demonstration:**

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import boto3
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr


def write_and_del_dynamodb(lock_pipe):
    _, lck_snd = lock_pipe
    dynamodb = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    add_params = {
        "TableName": "Testing",
        "Item": {
            "stream_url": {"S": "stream_url_test"},
            "added_time_utc": {"S": str(datetime.utcnow())},
        "ConditionExpression": 'attribute_not_exists(stream_url)'
    }

    del_params = {
        "TableName": "Testing",
        "Key": {'stream_url': {"S": 'stream_url_test'}}

    }

    lck_snd.send('LOCK_DOWN')
    print('''
    ================ ATOMIC WRITE-DELETE-WRITE PROCESS ====================
    ''')
    print('Putting an item...')
    dynamodb.put_item(**add_params)
    print('Sleeping for 1s...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Deleting an item...")
    dynamodb.delete_item(**del_params)
    print('Sleeping for 3s...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Putting an item...')
    dynamodb.put_item(**add_params)
    print('''
    ================ ATOMIC WRITE-DELETE-WRITE PROCESS ====================
    ''')
    lck_snd.send('LOCK_UP')


def read_dynamodb(lock_pipe):
    lck_rcv, _ = lock_pipe

    dynamodb = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    params = {
        "TableName": "Testing",
        "Key": {'stream_url': {"S": 'stream_url_test'}}

    }

    while lck_rcv.recv() != 'LOCK_UP':
        pass

    db_response = dynamodb.get_item(**params)
    items = db_response.get('Item')
    print(f'''
    ================ READ PROCESS ====================
    Data read:
        {items}
    ================ READ PROCESS ====================
    ''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock_pipe_receive, lock_pipe_send = Pipe()
    Process(name="write_and_del_dynamodb", target=write_and_del_dynamodb, args=((lock_pipe_receive, lock_pipe_send),)).start()
    time.sleep(1)
    Process(name="read_dynamodb", target=read_dynamodb, args=((lock_pipe_receive, lock_pipe_send),)).start()
```

in the code above two processes share the same resource, i.e., the `dynamoDB` data table `Testing`.
The working principle:

1. First process starts by sending a 'LOCK_DOWN' on the `lock_pipe_send` end, to signify the start of an atomic procedure.
2. First process writes some data to the `dynamoDB`.
3. First process deletes the data from the `dynamoDB`.
4. First process writed the data to the `dynamoDB` again.
5. The first process sends the 'LOCK_UP' on the `lock_pipe_send` end to signal the second process that the data may be read.
6. The second process (which was waiting on the `while lck_rcv.recv() != 'LOCK_UP'` condition) receives the `LOCK_UP` message, and reads the data from the dynamoDB.

**My question:**

How can I implement this behavior in a distributed manner, i.e., when I have the two processes sitting on different physical machines in the AWS, as shown in the following image? [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the [python-dynamodb-lock](https://pypi.org/project/python-dynamodb-lock/) package? It's based on the sort of "official" implementation of the pattern you describe in [Java](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-dynamodb-lock-client).

Comment: @Maurice - yes, but as it is not reliable in terms of node failure and delays it does not meet the requirements.

Comment: Wasn't there some built-in timeout that makes the locks able to be released if a node fails to prolong it, because it died?

Comment: @Maurice, yes, but as was described here: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html, there are scenarios which render there locks unreliable, and as reliability is a top priority for our project its not tolerable.